# How to display "SELECT" in dropdown list in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I a have a dropdown list which is being populated from database. It is working fine but in the view file I want the dropdown list to show "SELECT" on the very top of all values. Would you please kindly help me with this?

Thanks in Advance

I have this in my controller

```
 // To get the batch name
$this->load->model('dropdown_batchlist');
$data['dropdown_batchlist']= $this->dropdown_batchlist->dropdown_batchlist();
```

this in my model-

```
function dropdown_batchlist() {
$this->db->select('batchname, batchid');
$records=$this->db->get('batch');

            $data=array();

            foreach ($records->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data[$row->batchid] = $row->batchname;
                }

            return ($data);
        }
```

And this in my view file

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('batchid', $dropdown_batchlist ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add the 'SELECT' as the first item in the array:

```
function dropdown_batchlist() {
    $this->db->select('batchname, batchid');
    $records=$this->db->get('batch');

    $data=array();

    // add it here as the first item in the array, 
    // assuming you don't have a $row->batchid of 0 in your results.
    $data[0] = 'SELECT'; 

    foreach ($records->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[$row->batchid] = $row->batchname;
    }

    return ($data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Swatkins. It is working perfectly. Now would you please kindly help solve another problem? I want to validate the dropdown list using jquery and in order to do that I have to add - class="required" but I don't know where to put it. Would you please kindly help me again? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, in your view file, pass a string to the 4th parameter in your dropdown helper:  `<?php echo form_dropdown('batchid', $dropdown_batchlist, null, 'class="required"' ); ?>`